# How to style the parent DIV of a radio button to look like a card?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I select a radio button I want the wrapper parent div to style to `border: 1px solid #color` to look like a card. They way I did it with JavaScript works, but the code doesn't seem clean, ig?

There has to be a better way to do this, since I have seen this type of card-design in many websites before. How would you guys do select the parent div of the particular button the user clicks? Would you use JavaScript?

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form")
const parentDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".parentDiv")

form.addEventListener("change", e => {
  parentDivs.forEach(parent => {
    if(parent.getAttribute("aria-parent") == e.target.id) {
      parent.classList.add("selected")
    }else {
      parent.classList.remove("selected")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.parentDiv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.selected {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<h1>Select any of the button</h1>
<form>
  <label for="radio1">
    <div class="parentDiv" aria-parent="radio1">
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1">
      <div>
        <h2>Desk Stand 1</h2>
        <p>Some Dummy Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
  
  <label for="radio2">
    <div class="parentDiv" aria-parent="radio2">
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2">
      <div>
        <h2>Desk Stand 2</h2>
        <p>Some Dummy Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
  
  <label for="radio3">
    <div class="parentDiv" aria-parent="radio3">
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio3">
      <div>
        <h2>Desk Stand 3</h2>
        <p>Some Dummy Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: " but it doesn't look clean" , show us "clean" or even better yet inspect it with dev tools and re-create... Voting to close as it lacks clarity and is also opinion based, there is no real question here for SO:

Comment: @ikiK my question is if I even needed to use JavaScript? or is this okay? I used aria-*-*

Comment: @ikik aria tags are intended to be used for accessibility. It seems like you are using them to traverse the DOM.

Comment: @codechurn yes, sorry, I later realized that. what i meant to use was "data-" attribute

Answer (score 1):

I think that this would help you:
[Codepen preview](https://codepen.io/lehanmusthafa/pen/jOmxGqB)

**HTML**

```
<form class='form'>
  <label for="radio1">
    <div class="parentDiv" aria-parent="radio1">
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1">
      <div class ='flex'>
        <h2>Desk Stand 1</h2>
        <p>Some Dummy Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
  
  <label for="radio2">
    <div class="parentDiv" aria-parent="radio2">
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2">
      <div>
        <h2>Desk Stand 2</h2>
        <p>Some Dummy Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
  
  <label for="radio3">
    <div class="parentDiv" aria-parent="radio3">
      <input type="radio" name="radios" id="radio3">
      <div>
        <h2>Desk Stand 3</h2>
        <p>Some Dummy Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap');

body{ 
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 3rem;
}

#selected {
  border: 2px solid green;
  background: rgba(66, 245, 117, 0.2);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.parentDiv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const form = document.querySelector("form")
const parentDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".parentDiv")

form.addEventListener("change", e => {
  parentDivs.forEach(parent => {
    if(parent.getAttribute("aria-parent") == e.target.id) {
      parent.setAttribute('id','selected')
    }else {    parent.removeAttribute('id','selected')
    }
  })
})
```

Note:- Please change the styles to give it a more fresh look.

Comment: Thanks, but I will improve the design later in my real project. My question was, I saw some people do it using ChildNodes and ParentNodes to select the parent wrapper. I found that kind of a long work. So i used "aria". That's okay, right?